# authority_cert_issuer and authority_cert_serial_number must both be present or both None

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, anaconda, python-3.7

I'm using Python 3.7.1 in Anaconda 2018.12 and trying to make get() with requests from within a corporate network with custom certificates, I have the .pem for the certificate and I am using like so:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify='ssl/rootCA.pem')
print(response)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
File "run.py", line 29, in <module>
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify='ssl/rootCA.pem')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 355, in connect
cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 360, in getpeercert
'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 210, in get_subj_alt_name
ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\utils.py", line 162, in inner
result = func(instance)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py", line 137, in extensions
self._backend, self._x509
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py", line 252, in parse
value = handler(backend, ext_data)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py", line 376, in _decode_authority_key_identifier
key_identifier, authority_cert_issuer, authority_cert_serial_number
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 152, in __init__
"authority_cert_issuer and authority_cert_serial_number "

ValueError: authority_cert_issuer and authority_cert_serial_number must both be present or both None
```

My certificate is a pretty simple

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... certificate in here ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And I've used this method in the past with the same certificate (same .pem actually) before so I'm not sure what I must have done to cause this issue.

Comment: You mean you have google's cert-chain's root in that file (GlobalSign's self-signed cert)?

Comment: The URL is just an example of myself attempting to use requests.get(), the cert as far as I understand is my corporations,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by ditching Anaconda, just using Python and setting the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE path with:

```
set REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=C:\Users\User\workspaces\ssl\rootCA.pem
```